# Why doesn't 7 Days to Die save character progression in multi-player on PS4?

Tags: ps4, 7-days-to-die

I'm playing 7 Days to Die with 4 friends. In the first session we played for about 4 hours. We built a shared base & setup bedrolls etc.

In the second session everyone except the host had their characters reset (no experience points/ skill points, starting inventory, random spawn on map).

Is this expected behaviour? Could it be because non-host players are exiting before the host closes?

How do we get 7 Days to Die to save all character progress on PS4 multiplayer?

Comment: On Xbox (when the game runs without lagging out), I'm pretty sure it saves the characters for each game.  I'm not sure if there is a server setting the host can tweak for this or not though.

Comment: Did anyone experience any errors in the game during this time? I've run into issues with exceptions that will cause your game to crash and destroy the savegame.  The other option is to submit a bug report and see what happens. If it's reproducible by the forum moderators, then it might get sent to the developers.